# Is there any way to control thickness of cell border in TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am developing a Winform application with lots of `TableLayoutPanel` use.

If possible, I would like to set thickness of the cell borders zero or very small because hierarchical use of the `TableLayoutPanel` reduces width and height of actual cell contents.

I tried to search within MSDN and Google in vain. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked `TableLayoutPanel.CellBorderStyle` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.cellborderstyle(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Bolu Thanks for your comment. As far as I can see, however, that's nothing to do with its thickness. In my case, it's already `None`.

Comment: then you mean the `Margin` then, set `Margin` to 0|0|0|0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `Padding` and `Margin` of your `TableLayoutPanel` to `0|0|0|0`

[image]